# Header Access-Control-Allow-Headers has an invalid value

Tags: cors, wkwebview, ios14

On iOS 14, while testing the upgrade of my cordova app to WkWebView, a GET request triggered the following error

> Failed to load resource: Header Access-Control-Allow-Headers has an invalid value: "Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Authorization, Cache-Control, Connection, Content-Type, Host, my-custom-header, my-custom-header-two, Origin, Pragma, User-Agent"

This is how my backend is configured:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Authorization, Cache-Control, Connection, Content-Type, Host, my-custom-header, my-custom-header-two, Origin, Pragma, User-Agent"
```

This works just fine on iOS 12.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the quotes in the header did the trick. Seems it was ok for iOS 12 but not for iOS 14.

Wherever you may set your `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header, don't put quotes in there

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Authorization, Cache-Control, Connection, Content-Type, Host, my-custom-header, my-custom-header-two, Origin, Pragma, User-Agent
```

Note that Safari does not accept the wildcard for this CORS header, so you have specify every header you will ever send.

Hope this may help anyone encountering this.